# Speed up logical merging of rows in pandas (based on conditions)

Tags: pandas, performance, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame with millions of sales orders. Each row represents one item of a shopping cart. I need to merge orders, that are split despite being ordered on the same day. 
More precisely, all orders from the same customer on the same day which were also shipped on the same day should be assigned to the same order ID (regardless which one of the ones in question).

Columns: 'customer_id', 'order_id', ... , 'order_date', 'ship_date'

My naive solution works, but is horrifically slow:

```
for _, customer_groups in df.groupby(by='customer_id'):
        for _, same_day_orders in customer_groups.groupby(by=['order_date', 'ship_date']):
            # Only merge if multiple orders per day.
            if same_day_orders.shape[0] > 1:
                # Now step through the line items two at a time.
                row_iterator = same_day_orders.iterrows()
                _, last_row = next(row_iterator)
                for it in row_iterator:
                    idx, current_row = it
                    # Check if the next line order has the same 'ship_date' and a different 'order_id'...
                    same_shipping_date = (last_row.ship_date == current_row.ship_date)
                    different_order_id = (last_row.order_id is not current_row.order_id)
                    # ... if so, merge the rows by assigning the second line item the same 'order_id' as its predecessor.
                    if (same_shipping_date and different_order_id):
                        df.loc[idx, 'order_id'] = last_row.order_id
                    last_row = current_row
```

Example:

```
index   customer_id  order_id   order_date  ship_date
1234    C0176        S0159      2018-03-24  2018-04-23
1235    C0176        S0163      2018-03-24  2018-04-23
1236    C0176        S0163      2018-03-24  2018-04-23
1237    C0176        S0171      2018-03-24  2018-05-01

index   customer_id  order_id   order_date  ship_date   
1234    C0176        S0159      2018-03-24  2018-04-23
1235    C0176        S0159      2018-03-24  2018-04-23
1236    C0176        S0159      2018-03-24  2018-04-23
1237    C0176        S0171      2018-03-24  2018-05-01
```

How can I solve this problem in a smarter way, i.e., faster (retaining readability would be nice too)?

Comment: can you just groupby(['customer_id', 'order_date', 'ship_date'])

Comment: could you share a representative example of input data and output data (3 rows are enough, 2 to-be-grouped order and one independent one)

Comment: @sudonym I added a snipped, I hope that helps. The only change is in the 'order_id' column if the conditions are met.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great job for [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.transform.html), which performs a transformation on a grouped series but ensures that the index of the result matches the index of the input (rather than collapsing the groups into a single result, like what `agg` does).  You can use it like so:

```
# Get groups of equal customer_id, order_date, and ship_date:
groups = df.groupby(['customer_id', 'order_date', 'ship_date'])

# Get the last order_id value, but ensure its index matches df:
collapsed_orders = groups['order_id'].transform(lambda x: x.iloc[-1])

# Overwrite the original order_id with this new value:
df['order_id'] = collapsed_orders
```

Or, as a one-liner:

```
df['order_id'] = df.groupby(['customer_id', 'order_date', 'ship_date'])['order_id'].transform(lambda x: x.iloc[-1])
```

Comment: honestly - respect!